# Photoshop: possible to select hidden layers via keyboard shortcut?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, shortcuts

I use the Option + [ and ] keyboard shortcuts to select layers in Photoshop's layers panel, but it skips hidden layers. Is it possible at all to select these via the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

No. I don't believe hidden layers are selectable via *any* shortcut.